# Plotting a histogram in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

i have calculated two valuse with the code below

```
with open('paths_finished.tsv', 'rb') as tsvfile:
total = 0
count = 0
total2 = 0
count2 = 0
t = 0
for line in tsvfile:

   if '<;' in line:
        total += line.count(';')
        t += line.count('<;')
        count +=+1
   else:
        total2 += line.count(';') 
        count2 += 1

humanaverage = (total-t) / float(count)
computeraverage = total2 / float(count2)

print humanaverage

print computeraverage
```

output:

```
8.33285158421

4.72252533125
```

How do i plot these two walue in a histogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use bar:

```
bar([0,1],[8.33285158421,4.72252533125],width=1)
xticks([0.5,1.5],['humanaverage','computeraverage'])
```

Gives:

[image]

See also [the examples](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), like [this one](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html).